# android - RecyclerView items: how to save properties of Views in every row?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My problem is to understand how RecyclerView works.. I have `RecyclerView` with a little bit complicated item in every row, but the main thing is that Item has a child `ImageView` and `LinearLayout`. I want to press `ImageView` and set `Visibility` of `LinearLayout` to `GONE` or `VISIBLE` and rotate my `ImageView`. I tried to do this in my `onBindViewHolder`:

```
        holder.mIVExpandBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        boolean isOpen = false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isOpen) {
                CounterListAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
                holder.mLLDetails.setVisibility(GONE);
                holder.mDivider.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                holder.setArrowUp(false);
                isOpen = false;
                counterItem.setDetailsOpened(false);
            } else {
                holder.mLLDetails.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                holder.mDivider.setVisibility(GONE);
                holder.setArrowUp(true);
                isOpen = true;
                counterItem.setDetailsOpened(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

And I have some problems here.

- I have a boolean variable inside `OnClickListener`, I know its wrong, so it changes only one time when I expand my `LinearLayout`. If I make this boolean global variable, if I expand one row of RecyclerView `isOpen = true` for any other item and it doesn't expand itself when I click on ImageView.. Where should I place this boolean?
- And the second question - how can I save the state of my RecyclerView rows on screen rotation? For example I expanded one of my rows, `LinearLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE)`, change screen orientation and its closed.

Comment: do it where you initialise that button, in `ViewHolder' class

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, you should put your boolean variable where you also define your views, i.e., inside your ViewHolder, ir order that `onClick` you call the boolean this way

```
if(holder.isOpen)
```

In this way you keep the reference of each boolean to each row.

For your second problem, the solution is pretty simple. In your manifest, in the activity where you have your RecyclerView, define the following:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

This prevents your activity from being recreated on configuration change in case you rotate the screen, so the activity will keep it's state and your RecyclerView will therefor not be recreated along with your adapter.

Notice that this means that, if your activity is not recreated, `onPause`, `onStop`, etc, will not run. This is only for screen rotation, your activity will still run the method `onConfigurationChanged()` which is where you should define any changes you need in case the screen rotates.

Comment: Well, the first problem is solved, but I don't agree with the second. I know that using of configChanges in manifest is not a good idea according to the Google Docs.

Comment: It is not a good idea if you do not know how to handle it. You are basically telling the system "hey, I can handle the configuration change by myself, do not do it for me". You can search through out the web, I assure you 99% of the solutions is the one I just gave you

Comment: I use it almost all the time. And I explained in my answer a warning advice if you use it. Anyway, i edited my answer so you can have a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

You better put the OnClickListener in the Holder class, something like this:

```
private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        ....
        }
```

About how to save state I think all things that define the rows should be saved in the array you pass to the adapter contructor, you can add fields in the array item object that save VISIBILITY state of the row views.

On screen rotation then two options:

1 - as @Ricardo said avoiding Activity recreation

2 - onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceStates save/restore the array that define the rows .. my prefered method for that is to use JSON and put it in a String that can be saved/restored in the Bundle.

Comment: I used  onClick method in the VIewHolder class before and there was another problem. As we all know RecyclerView reuses it's items, so when I click "expand" on the first item and scroll my RecyclerView down I can easily find another expanded item :)

Comment: Each row must have its onOpen flag, if you use the same for all  you are expanding/collapsing all at once. Obviously.

Comment: Can you tell me more about it? What do you mean?

Comment: The same way you have a mLLDetails field in holder class add a mIsOpen field and instead to use isOpen use holder.mIsOpen.